# Calculating the number of trials to get all four outcomes

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I was posed the following question recently:

> Suppose a brand of cereal has four different toys included in their cereal boxes, each with an equal probability of being found: ***On average, how many boxes of cereal do you need to buy to get all four toys?***

Since getting a toy in each box is an independent event and the probability stays constant, I guessed that you could model this using the binomial distribution:

\begin{align}
X &= \text{number of unique toys}\\
X &\sim B(n, 0.25)
\end{align}

Where $n$ is the number of trials. The probability function for getting four unique toys would therefore be:

$$P(X = 4) = {n \choose 4} \cdot 0.25^4 \cdot 0.75^{n-4}$$

So, to find the mean number of trials, I perform the infinite sum:

$$\sum \limits_{n=4}^\infty \left[n\cdot P(X=4)\right] = \sum \limits_{n=4}^\infty \left[n\cdot {n \choose 4} \cdot 0.25^4 \cdot 0.75^{n-4}\right]$$

Which, when I plug this into Wolfram Alpha returns $76$.

So, according to my calculation, on average you need to buy $76$ boxes of cereal to get all four toys. Is this right?

Comment: $$\frac44+\frac43+\frac42+\frac41=8+\frac13$$

Comment: @Did Huh, that's smaller than I expected